# How to get challenges and responses from NLP Captcha

Tags: nlp

I have recently used a PhP script to pull Google recaptcha into my web page, and now I'd like to do the same with NLP Captcha.

But I am stuck at how to submit the challenge and response. This is the first time I use NLP Captcha.

In recaptcha I used to get the challenge and response this way:

```
$c = $_REQUEST['recaptcha_challenge_field'];
$cv = $_REQUEST['recaptcha_response_field'];
```

and submitting this way:

```
$post_data2 = "recaptcha_challenge_field=$c&recaptcha_response_field=$cv";
```

But how do I do this using NLP Captcha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding fields in NLPCaptcha would be

```
$c=$_POST['nlpIdentifier'];
$cv=$_POST['nlpAnswer'];
```

and would be submitted to our validation server as

```
$post_data2 = "nlpIdentifier=$c&nlpAnswer=$cv";
```

Integration of our captcha is straight forward and we also provide ready
made integration kits for most common programming platforms(java/php/dotnet/ruby).

In case the provided kits do not satisfy your specific needs, custom
integration is fairly easy and straight forward.

To get access to the integration kits and related documentation, please create a ticket by visiting http://support.nlpcaptcha.in and it will be directly answered by our support staff!

Regards

Team NLPCaptcha

http://www.nlpcaptcha.com